# Detecting inactivity from AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mavericks

I have an AppleScript that warns me when the screen is about to lock and go to screensaver because of the mouse and keyboard being idle. However, it warns me when I am watching a video.

Here is a snippet of the current way I'm detecting idle time:

```
set idleTime to (do shell script "ioreg -c IOHIDSystem | awk '/HIDIdleTime/ {print int($NF/1000000000); exit}'") as number
```

Is there a better way in AppleScript to detect inactivity (especially around watching videos) than doing the above?

I'm on OSX-Mavericks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the manual page for "pmset". There is the whole thing described. 
It can list assertions.

```
pmset -g
```

You can check that way if the power management has any such assertions...

For example, when VLC is playing a movie, "pmset -g" shows:

```
 displaysleep 10 (display sleep prevented by VLC)
```

Comment: Yes, I think something is going to be workable here. Thank you.

Comment: Nice :) I never used 'pmset' really but a while ago I had to find out how to prevent display-sleep ("dynamically override these power management settings by using I/O Kit power assertions") and with that in mind I found pmset in Terminal. ("pm" stands for PowerManagement" so that helped :)